# Using the next button to replace content on my page, without redirecting me to a new page

Tags: php, mysql, button, radio-button

I'm trying to make a quiz application that shows answers with radio buttons on the sides. When you press the next button a set of new answers will appear and replace the .

I've managed to make four questions pop up as intended and four new ones popup when I press the next button.
Right now theres one problem, my first set of four answers (with qid = 1) does not dissapear, which is weird since the other set of answers with qid = 2 and 3 does and replace eachother whenever I press the next button.

How do I make it so that the new answers appear and replace the old answers?

Here is my code so far PHP:

```
$qid1 = 1;

$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where qid ='$qid1'");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{

echo "<input type='radio' name='answer1' value='".$row['Point']."'>"
        .$row['answer'] ."<br>";

}
echo "<input type='submit' name='forward1' value='next'>";
$qid2 = 2;

$sql2 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where qid ='$qid2'");


while($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)){
if (isset($_POST['forward1'])) {


echo "<input type='radio' name='answer2' value='".$row2['Point']."'>"
        .$row2['answer'] ."<br>";

}
}

echo "<input type='submit' name='forward2' value='next'>";
$qid3 = 3;

$sql3 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where qid ='$qid3'");

while($row3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3)){
if (isset($_POST['forward2'])) {


echo "<input type='radio' name='answer3' value='".$row3['Point']."'>"
        .$row3['answer'] ."<br>";

}
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='forward3' value='next'>";
```

Comment: it would help if you a) posted the entire code, and b) asked a question. it seems stupid but it really does make things clearer if you actually ask a question.

Comment: See my edit "
How do I make it so that the new answers from my database appear and replace the old answers, instead of appearing under the old answers?"

Comment: @Pamblam this is my entire PHP code in my page

Comment: see i'm still having a hard time figuring out how the form is submitting at all without any `<form />` tags.

Comment: in fact that's most likely the issue right there.. i'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate your inputs with form tags. For each of your loops do something like this..

```
echo "<form>";
$sql3 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where qid ='$qid3'");
while($row3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3)){
    if (isset($_POST['forward2'])) {
        echo "<input type='radio' name='answer3' value='".$row3['Point']."'>"
        .$row3['answer'] ."<br>";
    }
}
echo "<input type='submit' name='forward3' value='next'>";
echo "</form>";
```

---

Try this..

```
<?php

$localhost = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$connect = mysqli_connect($localhost, $username, $password) || die("Kunde inte koppla");
mysqli_select_db($connect, 'wildfire');

// let's put the qid in a session var
session_start();
$qid = isset($_SESSION['qid']) ? $_SESSION['qid']+1 : 1;
$_SESSION['qid'] = $qid;

ob_start();

echo "<form>";
$sql1 = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM question where qid ='$qid'");

while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1))
    echo "<input type='radio' name='answer1' value='{$row1['Point']}'>{$row1['answer']}<br>";

echo "<input type='submit' name='forward1' value='next'>";
echo "</form>";


$output = ob_get_clean();


?>

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body> 
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that right now, nothing really happens when I press the next button, no new answers appear. What do I do now?

Comment: well, the short answer is, you must have required one of the other inputs in the long run on form. you could try wrapping ALL the inputs in a single form instead of making one form per input. I can really only guess without seeing the full code. there's no way this is the complete application there is no database connection, there is no variables from the submitted form anywhere.. i need the entire code to be able to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Alright, ill send you the full code, including the database contents: http://codepad.viper-7.com/xkGueK 

My database that I'm connecting to consists of: 

qid (int), answer(varchar), Point (int)

Comment: Thank you, it works. One problem I'm facing right now is that when I saw the answers I pressed the next button to check that all of the answers would show, which they did. Problem is, I cant see the answers anymore even when I refresh the page. What do I do?

Comment: @PHPScrub  here's the thing. you keep marking my answer and then unmarking it because i won't answer every question you have in a single thread. i spent time on your problem and solved the one you asked about. if you have a new question you post a new answer, you don't try to extort one out of the people who help you by refusing to give them credit for the FREE work they did for you. please mark my answer, and then go read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.